# How to put CAPSPageMenu with auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

hi I want to know how to put CAPSMenu above my greyLine. I try and use frame from the page menu the result is white screen. I never use frame before, since when I learn iOS programming they abandon using frame. since it an old way doing it. this is my setup and my code. where did I do wrong?

[image: menu]

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupContainer()
        setupPageMenu()
    }

    private func setupContainer() {
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(backBtn)
        containerView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(separatorView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 187),

            backBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 50),
            backBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),

            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: 23),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),

            separatorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            separatorView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
            separatorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            separatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2)
        ])
    }

    private func setupPageMenu() {
        let profileVC =  UIViewController()
        profileVC.title = "VC 1"
        viewControllers.append(profileVC)

        let scheduleVC = UIViewController()
        scheduleVC.title = "VC 2"
        viewControllers.append(scheduleVC)

        let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
            .menuItemSeparatorWidth(0.0),
            .useMenuLikeSegmentedControl(true),
            .menuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(0.0),
            .selectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor(red: 18.0/255.0, green: 150.0/255.0, blue: 225.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
            .scrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor.white),
            .selectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(red: 18.0/255.0, green: 150.0/255.0, blue: 225.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0))
           ]

        gPageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: viewControllers, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: containerView.frame.width, height: 33), pageMenuOptions: parameters)
        gPageMenu.delegate = self
        containerView.addSubview(gPageMenu.view)
    }
```

Comment: How is the rest of your view setup? containerView hierarchy and constraints?

Comment: @valosip I update the question, since I want to add the constrain but stack overflow asking there is too much code.

Comment: @FerryAdiWijayanto Try to set  `gPageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: viewControllers, frame: CGRect(x:  separatorView.frame.origin.x, y: separatorView.frame.origin.y - 10, width: containerView.frame.width, height: 33), pageMenuOptions: parameters)`

Comment: it just above the container @KishanBhatiya

Comment: put a breakpoint where you're creating gPageMenu and print out the `containerView.frame.width` value.  I bet its 0